# How do I disable autcomplete on space in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, editor, settings, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2022, I often will run into an issue where I am typing a smaller word and, when I press `SPACE`, VS auto-completes it to something completely unrelated to the context that just happened to be the highest in the IntelliSense suggestion popup. How do I change this behavior to only auto-complete/accept suggestions when you press `TAB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion`

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can consider accepting it as answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.